# What's the difference between PerThreadQueuedDispatcher and ImmediateDispatcher in guava?

Tags: java, guava

The dispatch() method of ImmediateDispatcher is:

```
void dispatch(Object event, Iterator<Subscriber> subscribers) {
  checkNotNull(event);
  while (subscribers.hasNext()) {
    subscribers.next().dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

it just dispatch event to each subscrriber, so this is easy to understand.

However, the same method of PerThreadQueuedDispatcher is:

```
// both queue and dispatching are ThreadLocal.
@Override
void dispatch(Object event, Iterator<Subscriber> subscribers) {
  checkNotNull(event);
  checkNotNull(subscribers);
  Queue<Event> queueForThread = queue.get();
  queueForThread.offer(new Event(event, subscribers)); 
  // Isn't dispatching.get() always return false? Why the if then?
  if (!dispatching.get()) { 
    dispatching.set(true);
    try {
      Event nextEvent;
      while ((nextEvent = queueForThread.poll()) != null) {
        while (nextEvent.subscribers.hasNext()) {
          nextEvent.subscribers.next().dispatchEvent(nextEvent.event);
        }
      }
    } finally {
      dispatching.remove();
      queue.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

I have questions about this method:

1. What's the point of encapsulating event and subscribers into an Event object and offer it to a threadlocal queue, and then poll it out to perform the  same logic that ImmediateDispatcher.dispatch() does?
2. Isn't dispatching.get() always return false? Why the if then?

Comment: The code had pretty detailed explanation... https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/Dispatcher.java

Comment: @Taylor It would seem OP is already looking at the code...

Comment: @shmosel I know, but the explanation of his (first question at least) is right there.

Comment: The key thing you seem to have missed (and which isn't necessarily obvious just from looking at the code) is that the `dispatchEvent` call inside the loop can end up calling `dispatch` again on the same thread if the subscriber method that's called posts another event. That's how `dispatching` can be true. @shmosel's answer explains the effect this has on dispatch order.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is when one event triggers another. Suppose we have an event A that triggers events B and C, and event B in turn triggers event D:

```
class Test {
    class A {}
    class B {}
    class C {}
    class D {}

    EventBus bus = new EventBus();

    Test() {
        bus.register(this);
        bus.post(new A());
    }

    @Subscribe void listen(A obj) {
        System.out.println("A");
        bus.post(new B());
        bus.post(new C());
    }

    @Subscribe void listen(B obj) {
        System.out.println("B");
        bus.post(new D());
    }

    @Subscribe void listen(C obj) {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    @Subscribe void listen(D obj) {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}
```

We can think of these events as a sort of tree, where each event spawns additional "child" events:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 /
D
```

There are two common ways of traversing a tree: depth-first (A, B, D, C) and breadth-first (A, B, C, D). That's the difference between the two dispatchers.

The immediate dispatcher processes events as they're created, resulting in depth-first dispatching. The queued dispatcher queues up events as they're submitted and processes them by polling the queue, resulting in breadth-first dispatching. The `dispatching` flag is used to restrict queue processing to the root event. Child events will find the flag set and move along.